# Binding outputs of transformers in FeatureUnion

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

New to python and sklearn so apologies in advance. I have two transformers and I would like to gather the results in a `FeatureUnion (for a final modelling step at the end). This should be quite simple but FeatureUnion is stacking the outputs rather than providing an nx2 array or DataFrame. In the example below I will generate some data that is 10 rows by 2 columns. This will then generate two features that are 10 rows by 1 column. I would like the final feature union to have 10 rows and 1 column but what I get are 20 rows by 1 column.

I will try to demonstrate with my example below:

some imports

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import pipeline
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
```

some random data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 2), columns=['a', 'b'])
```

a custom transformer that selects a column

```
class Trans(TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, col_name):
        self.col_name = col_name
    def fit(self, X):
        return self                                                                    
    def transform(self, X):                                                           
        return X[self.col_name]
```

a pipeline that uses the transformer twice (in my real case I have two different transformers but this reproduces the problem)

```
pipe = pipeline.FeatureUnion([
    ('select_a', Trans('a')),
    ('select_b', Trans('b'))
    ])
```

now i use the pipeline but it returns an array of twice the length

```
pipe.fit_transform(df).shape

(20,)
```

however I would like an array with dimensions (10, 2).

Quick fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transformers in the `FeatureUnion` need to return 2-dimensional matrices, however in your code by selecting a column, you are returning a 1-dimensional vector. You could fix this by selecting the column with `X[[self.col_name]]`.